# Microsoft Word Table of Contents displays the color of the numbered list instead of the color in the TOC style

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

In a Microsoft Word 2013 document I have defined Heading 1 and Heading 2 to be a numbered list in a blue font.

When I generate the TOC the text of the TOC line is black but the number from the entry is blue. I want the TOC to be all black and have verified that style TOC1 and style TOC2 do have black listed as the font.

For example, if a heading in the body of the document is all blue and is "1.0 Introduction" then in the TOC the "1.0" would be blue but "Introduction" would be black. I want them both to be black.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

NOTE - I just resolved the problem by deleting the TOC and then re-adding it. For some reason updating the TOC is somehow different than delete/re-adding.

Comment: Please post solutions as a separate answer. It's absolutely fine to answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue recently and later realized I had track changes on so every time I updated my table or tried to change its formatting, the TOC would remain blue. Once track changes are turned off it goes back to black (or whatever color you've chosen).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you sure it is related?  OP stated it was solved by deleting and re-adding.  One presumes that track changes would have continued to highlight changes unless OP shut that off as well.